# t-SQL and ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE for renaming tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two SQL Server 2008 scripts that can be executed from an ASP.NET script simultaneously.

Here's one:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

--select, delete, update, insert rows in Table1

COMMIT;
SET XACT_ABORT OFF;
```

And then this statement to rename and delete table:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

EXEC sp_rename 'Table1', 'Table2';  --rename Table1 into Table2
DROP TABLE Table1;

COMMIT;
SET XACT_ABORT OFF;
```

My question is, as you can see I'm using `ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` to address the issue of those two running at the same type by letting only one run, but my question is, does this mutual exclusion affect the `EXEC sp_rename` SQL command?

Answer (score 0):

sp_rename is not affected by isolation level.  Isolation level affects locking and row versioning. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx You don't need this isolation level for either of these, you cannot rename a table that has locks on it from a select, insert, or update.